# jquery to pure Javascript to keep Vertical Rhythm for images

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the quest for a solution to keep vertical rhythm for images I found this excellent script from **Filipe Fortes** http://www.fortes.com/2008/jmetronome-using-jquery-to-keep-typographic-rhythm :

```
        $(function() {
          var lineHeight = parseInt($('body').css('line-height'));
          function balanceHeight(el) {
              var h = $(el).outerHeight();
              var delta = h % lineHeight;
              if (delta != 0)
              {
                /* For images and objects, we want to align the bottom w/ the baseline, so we
                 * pad the top of the element. For other elements (text elements that have a
                 * scrollbar), we pad the bottom, to keep the text within on the same baseline */
                var paddingDirection = ($(el).is('img') || $(el).is('object')) ?
                                                      'padding-top' : 'padding-bottom';

                /* Adjust padding, because margin can get collapsed and cause uneven spacing */
                  var currentPadding = parseInt($(el).css(paddingDirection));
                  $(el).css(paddingDirection, currentPadding + lineHeight - delta);
              }
          }

          /* Depending on your content, you may want to modify which elements you want to adjust,
           * by modifying the selector used below. By default, we grab all img, pre, and object
           * elements. */
          $('img').each(function() {
              /* Only works if we're manipulating block objects */
              if ($(this).css('display') == 'inline')
              {
                  $(this).css('display', 'block');
              }

              /* Images need to load before you get their height */
              if ($(this).is('img'))
              {
                  $(this).load(function(){ balanceHeight(this); });
              }
              else
              {
                  balanceHeight(this);
              }
          });
        })
```

It works quite good for me but since I'm working on a mobile project, I'm wondering on how to translate it to pure javascript.

Comment: Why? jQuery works on most mobile devices. They even have a [mobile UI framework](http://jquerymobile.com/).

Comment: Since I don't need the most part of these libraries I want to keep things simple and fast. An interesting quote: “Just some pure JavaScript without a framework and using the capabilities of the target platform as much as possible allows for a lean page that loads almost instantly, caches well and works great offline. Yes, we could have used JavaScript and CSS frameworks, but sometimes less is more (and remember, you don’t need all the cross-browser heavy lifting that frameworks do for you).” Thomas Fuchs

Comment: Sure, if you're only targeting one or two combinations of devices and browsers. If you're targeting any mobile device, however, you'll need to do a ton of cross browser checking without a library like jQuery (way more than you would for a desktop web site).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a straight code conversion request which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

To translate this to standard JavaScript, you need to do a few things:

1. Change the selectors (ex. `var images = documents.getElementsByTagName('img')`)
2. Change the jQuery objects (ex. instead of `.each()`, we use a `for` loop. Take the following example:

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i += 1) {
     // code here
   }
   ```

If you would like me go into more detail, please leave me a comment. It won't be too difficult to translate this function.

Comment: Thank you! I've some trouble in translating `$(el).outerHeight();` and most of all `$(this).load(function(){ balanceHeight(this); });`

Comment: The `.each()` function is passing its context to the `balanceHeight()` function. In your `for` loop, you can pass `images[i]` into that function. For example, `for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i += 1) { balanceHeight(images[i]); }`. `$(el).outerHeight();` can be translated once you have `images[i]` passed as `el` into `balanceHeight()` as `var h = el.outerHeight;`.